# Same Azure AD access token for Multiple Resources

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are evaluating an option if the "same" azure AAD access token be used to access multiple webapis.
Here is the flow :

```
Client -> webapi1 -> webapi2

1) client authenticates against AAD and acquires token1 <br>
2) client calls webapi1 with token1<br>
3) webapi1 calls webapi2 with token1
```

Lets say both the webapi's are configured to validate the same audience ('xxxx') and authority, are there any complications/security issue to leverage the same token for both the apis.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: I am curious why you want to do this? I can think of some reasons, but would like to hear what is your reasoning.

Comment: One reason is to avoid a round trip to AAD to fetch a token specific to webapi2.

Comment: Right, though you can cache the token :) Hopefully you are not optimising too early.

Comment: But I want to know the cons of this approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case webapi1 and webapi2 are essentially the same API as far as Azure AD is concerned.

One con of this approach is possibly too many privileges on the APIs.

Let's say API A requires access to all users' emails in the organization. Now since API B is effectively the same app from AAD's point of view, it also gets this right, though it didn't need it.

Typically we try to follow the principle of least privilege, where every part of the app has exactly the access it needs, and no more. So using the same audience again can go against this.

Another issue is that another app which has rights to call API A also gets rights to call API B.

I can understand your reasoning for avoiding the round trip of fetching an additional token, but tokens can be cached.